# @Service and @Repository beans not initializing in Spring boot and Apache camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

In my camel and spring boot application, I have a simple route: folder->processor->folder.

In the processor the service and repository are always null. In the test classes these are not null.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception
{
    from("file:input")
    .log("from file")
    .process(new MyProcessor())
    .to("file:destination")
    .log("to destination")`
    .end();
}
```

Am I missing anything. Why are the respository and service beans null in the processor but work fine in the test classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are manually creating a processor via `new MyProcessor()`, meaning Spring will not autowire the dependencies for you.

You should use [Camel Bean support](https://camel.apache.org/bean.html) instead:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception
{
    from("file:input")
    .log("from file")
    .bean("myProcessor")
    .to("file:destination")
    .log("to destination")`
    .end();
}
```

Or, if your `MyProcessor` bean implements Camel's `Processor`, you could do something like this:

```
@Autowired
private MyProcessor processor;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception
{
    from("file:input")
    .log("from file")
    .processor(processor)
    .to("file:destination")
    .log("to destination")`
    .end();
}
```